# How to $pull in mongodb if you have a weird data inside an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So basically I have this data

```
{
  company: {
    subscriptions: [
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
      },
      {
        "name": "test2",
        "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
      },
      {
        "services": {
          "1": {
            "createdAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z"),
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
          }
        },
        "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently I don't know how this data is inserted on the collection.

The weird data is this one.

```
{
        "services": {
          "1": {
            "createdAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z"),
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
          }
        },
        "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-10-19T06:40:33.583Z")
      }
```

How can I use mongodb $pull to remove this inside subscriptions array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on @Takis_ answer I found a solution. Here is what I did.

```
const cursor = await Company.find({
    $and: [
      {
        "subscriptions": { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
      }
    ]
  }).cursor();


  await cursor.eachAsync(async company => {
    let isUpdate = false;

    const found = find(company.subscriptions, subscription => subscription.name === undefined);

    if (!found) return

    try {
      const res = await Company.updateOne(
        {
          "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id),
        },
        {
          $pull: { subscriptions: { name: { $exists: false } } }
        }
      );
    } catch(err) {
      log(`ERROR removing subscription entry for company ${company.name} - ${company._id}`);
    }
  })
```

Although @Takis has the right answer this one works for me on my end

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- $pull, if member doesnt have a field called name, it gets removed

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ZlIxbYsXAt)

```js
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  $pull: {
    "company.subscriptions": {
      name: {
        "$exists": false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Query2

- alternative way with pipeline
- this removes a member of the array, if doesnt have a field `name`
  (or name is false/null)
- services that you dont want to remove doesnt have a name so it will be filtered out

> pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1QEKktQD3Fd)

```js
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "company.subscriptions": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$company.subscriptions",
          "cond": "$$this.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If your updateMany method doesnt accept pipeline you can run it like as command

```js
db.runCommand(
   {
      update: "yourCollection",
      updates: [
         {
           q: { },
           u: [
               {
                 "$set": {
                  "company.subscriptions": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$company.subscriptions",
                       "cond": "$$this.name"
                   }
              }}}
           ],
           multi: true
         }
      ],
      ordered: false
   }
)
```

Comment: I got this error `Invalid query: Line 1: Expected '(' instead of 'M'` if I use `updateMany `

Comment: you could do it also with array filters and `$pull`. Here is the [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) but the most important is the [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) , that has all the type of operators with examples

Comment: Thank you so much for the links and your answers

Comment: that code works on shell, on nodejs, maybe its small difference, on the call way, iam searching for it

Comment: I already found a solution thank you so much

Comment: i updated the answer, added a `$pull` solution and a way to run the update pipeline even if updateMethod doesnt accept pipeline in nodejs. You need only 1 update many command not many find/updateOne.